# Pytest does not collect nested Test_* classes

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing, pytest, vscode-extensions

I am writing a test suite with pytest to cover an API, with tests organized like this:

```
class Test_Endpoint:
    def test_A(self):
        ...
    def test_B(self):
        ...

    class Test_SubEndpoint:
        def test_C(self):
            ...
```

Pytest has collected and run tests inside the Test_SubEndpoint class previously, but has suddenly stopped and will only collect and run tests which are not class functions or are members of a root level test class. Previously, test_A test_B and test_C were all collected, but now only test_A and test_B are collected, and I am not aware of any changes I made which would cause this.

It's also no longer grouping parametrized tests in VSCode's test viewer, but I'm not sure if that's an issue with pytest or with VSCode.

The pytest.ini file contents are

```
[pytest]
addopts = --self-contained-html
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
pythonpath = .
```

and were not changed when this problem started happening. When I add explicit definitions for `python_files`, `python_classes`, and `python_functions` which match my naming conventions to the pytest.ini file, it does not affect my issue. My file, class, and function names are in line with the pytest default naming conventions.

Flattening the class structure in my test files does work to get all tests collected, but it loses the organizational aid that I've been relying on during development and doesn't fix the lack of parametrized test grouping, so I'd really prefer to be able to preserve the nested structure.

Comment: Can not reproduce.  All 3 test are collected in your example using pytest 7.4.0 on Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue with the python extension for Visual Studio Code. The extension had updated to `v2023.12.0`, when I discussed this with a colleague and reverted to version `v2023.4.1` at his recommendation, the problem is resolved.

Nested test classes are correctly collected and displayed in the side menu testing viewer and when running `pytest --collect-only` in the integrated terminal, and parametrized tests are properly displaying their specified IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `pytest` discovery rules in a `pytest.ini` file:

```ini
[pytest]
# Set pytest discovery rules:
# (Most of the rules here are similar to the default rules.)
# (Inheriting unittest.TestCase could override these rules.)
python_files = test_*.py *_test.py *_tests.py *_suite.py
python_classes = Test* *Test* *Test *Tests *Suite
python_functions = test_*
```

Also, if not using pytest fixtures, you can have your test classes inherit `unittest.TestCase`, which automatically makes them discoverable.

Comment: Do you know if * can match empty strings in those definitions?

Comment: `*` will match on any character in the string for the file name, class name, and test name.